# Mule returning null when RequestContext.getEvent()

Tags: mule

During `org.mule.component.BindingInvocationHandler` invoke method Mule is trying to get the Current Event from `RequestContext.getEvent();`
But the value is coming as Null and we are getting `NullPointerException`.
What could be the reason that sets `CurrentEvent` of `RequestContext` to null?

Update: We are using java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService to invoke a method bound by BindingInvocationHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestContext.getEvent()` uses `ThreadLocal` to find out the in-flight event so maybe you're calling it from within a thread that is not the one that processes the `MuleEvent`?

If that's the case, you can try cloning the event then passing it to your thread and re-establish it as the current event with `RequestContext.setEvent(xxx)`.

Expect turbulence as this is not small feat, though Mule does this internally.

Use the `newThreadCopy()` on the event to get a copy that can be processed by another Mule thread without throwing an exception.

Comment: Exactly, we are calling it using a threading mechanisum. which uses Cached ThreadPool - java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.
How can we get pass this error if we still need to use the ExecutorService

Comment: Added some suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try out your suggestion and reply back at the earliest.